# iphone gdb breakpoint is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

my iphone(and my friend's iphone too)'s breakpoint(in gdb) is not working!
i'm downloaded gdb in cydia
does any one knows about this problems ?

```
Tester-ui-iPhone:/tmp root# uname -a
Darwin Tester-ui-iPhone 11.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Tue Nov  1 20:33:22 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1878.4.46~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8920X iPhone2,1 arm N88AP Darwin
Tester-ui-iPhone:/tmp root# gdb test
GNU gdb 6.3.50.20050815-cvs (Fri May 20 08:08:42 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=arm-apple-darwin9 --target="...
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2d2e
(gdb) r
Starting program: /private/var/tmp/test
Syntax: /private/var/tmp/test <arg>
Program exited with code 01.
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to breakpoint in a specific app?
If so, you need to attach to the process first with
attach target

For example you want to attach to Fruit Ninja game. When attaching the you need to attach to the binary part which is not always the same as the app name.

attach Fruit

Alternatively you could search for a process id and attach to that.

Once you are attached you can set a breakpoint using

b *0x00123456

or if you have the function name

b function()

If you experience any crashing, try this

handle SIGKILL stop